# Is list-column a concept in the R language?

Tags: r

Is list-column data structure  a concept in the R language or not?

What is a list column? When viewing a dataframe as a list of columns, is a list column a column in the dataframe?

I got the confusion from *[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1)*

> List-columns are  implicit  in  the  definition  of  the  data  frame:
>   a  data  frame  is  a named list of equal length vectors. A list is a
>   vector, so it’s always been legitimate to use a list as a column of a
>   data frame. However, base  R  doesn’t  make  it  easy  to  create 
>   list-columns,  and data.frame()  treats a list as a list of columns:
>
> ```
> data.frame(x = list(1:3, 3:5))
> #>   x.1.3 x.3.5
> #> 1     1     3
> #> 2     2     4
> #> 3     3     5
> ```
>
> You  can  prevent  data.frame()   from  doing  this  with  I() ,  but 
>   the result doesn’t print particularly well:
>
> ```
> data.frame(
>   x = I(list(1:3, 3:5)),
>   y = c("1, 2", "3, 4, 5")
> )
> #>         x       y
> #> 1 1, 2, 3    1, 2
> #> 2 3, 4, 5 3, 4, 5
> ```

Comment: I think your question boils down to 'does _R for Data Science_ define the R language'.

Comment: You can have a list-column in a data.frame. `df <- data.frame(y = 1:2);df$x <- list(1:3, 3:5)`

Comment: @BenBolker What is the definition of a list column?

Comment: @RonakShah What is the definition of a list column?

Comment: a column of a data frame of type 'list'

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, please avoid snark if possible (feel free to downvote/vote to close as you see fit ...)

Comment: @Newbie, I think it would help to edit your question to drop the first question ("is it a concept"), and re-title your question accordingly. Your other questions are much clearer and answerable.

Comment: @BenBolker Does it make sense to talk about list-column in the R language?

Comment: @BenBolker I am actually dead-serious, and looked into list-columns recently. It is an interesting question.

Comment: OK, sorry about that - I took it as snark.

Comment: @BenBolker For the record, your first comment is really bad. It makes it look as if _only_ the tidyverse supported them.  However, e.g. the `mlr3` project is happy to make *extensive use* of list-columns via `data.table`.  Now, `R for Data Science` does not mention or allude to any of that? Should it? Should it not?  Should it not mentions list columns _for mere lack of `print` support in base `data.frame`_ ?  I really do not know.

Comment: OK, deleted my comment.  (Note that the first comment of my mine that appears above, previously my second comment, is not the one @DirkEddelbuettel is objecting to ...)

Answer (score 1):

Not only are list-columns *concepts* in R and the `tidyverse`, sometimes they're nearly unavoidable.  Mostly, the contents of each cell in a tibble (or dataFrame) is a number, character or logical.  But the contents *can* be a vector, a list, or a tibble.  Often the next step, when you've created one of those, is to `unnest`.  For example, look at the terms with `and` in this tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
inputs <- tibble(Veggies = c("carrots", "potatoes and onions", "squash"),
                   Herbs = c("parsley", "sage", "rosemary and thyme"))
```

We want to give each conjoined term its own line, like this:

```
splitPea <- inputs %>% 
  mutate(Veggies = str_split(Veggies, "\\s+and\\s+"),
         Herbs = str_split(Herbs, "\\s+and\\s+"))
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Veggies   Herbs    
  <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
2 <chr [2]> <chr [1]>
3 <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
```

Note that each column is a list, and the cell-contents are vectors.  Now `unnest`:

```
splitPea %>% 
  unnest(c(Veggies, Herbs))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Veggies  Herbs   
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 carrots  parsley 
2 potatoes sage    
3 onions   sage    
4 squash   rosemary
5 squash   thyme
```

PS, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878290/mutate-to-add-two-columns-with-a-single-fn-call-in-tidyverse-in-r) to see why + how you'd make a column of a list of tibbles.